# Prove that every closed set $A \subset \mathbb{R} $ is also closed as a subset $A \subset \mathbb{C} $

Tags: analysis

Show that every  closed set $A  \subset \mathbb{R}  $ is also closed as a subset $A  \subset \mathbb{C}  $. And wich properties must holds that a open set $A  \subset \mathbb{R}  $ is also open in $A  \subset \mathbb{C}  $?

Comment: Hint for the first part: if $z \in \mathbb C$ and the imaginary part of $z$ is nonzero, can $z$ be a limit point of $A$?

Comment: the second statement is always wrong. Unless $A$ is empty...

Comment: @yanko Nope. There is one exception.

Comment: I am not sure if i get it right: But in this example we are only interested in the "x-axis", because there is no imaginary part in $\mathbb{R} $? So the imaginary part is unimportant .

Answer (score 1):

$\mathbb{R}$ is closed in $\mathbb{C}$, so every closed subset of $\mathbb{R}$ is closed in $\mathbb{C}$ as well.

Comment: Okay but this is not a theorem in our course. This is a basic analysis course and this is the 4 week

Comment: @AnnaSaabel And "the intersection if closed sets is closed" is not part of the curriculum?

Answer (score 0):

Note that $x _n+iy _n\to x+iy\iff x _n\to x \quad\text{and} \quad y _n\to y$. In particular if there is a sequence $x_n+i0\to x+iy$ what can we conclude about $y$.

Comment: Sorry i forgot to say, that we didn't have sequence yet.

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure but I think this is the general idea? $S = \{z \in \mathbb{C} | a \in A\}$ Let x be an accumulation point of A. Then, $x \in A$. Also since S is a construction of A, $x \in re(S)$.

I think the key is $im(z) = 0$, since there is no imaginary part in $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 0):

I think the Rudin's theorem can help

**2.30 Theorem:** Suppose 
$Y\subset X.$
A subset $E$ of $Y$ is open relative to 
$Y$
iff 
$E=Y\cap G$
for some open subset
$G$ 
of 
$X.$

Also, Please note that the other comments in order to complete your answer.

Comment: Thank you, but this is not a theorem in our course. This is a basic analysis course and this is the 4 week.

Comment: you may use it and its proof. Rudin W. Principles of Mathematical Analysis